# Problema al definir una función con las variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo que añadir un alumno nuevo a la lista ya creada.

Para ello primero defino las variables con nombre y apellido de los alumnos de la clase y con ellos creo una nueva variable que lista todos los `alumnosclase`.

```
#Variables con nombres de cada alumno
alumno1 = ["Bruce", "Lee"] 
alumno2 = ["Jet", "Li"]
alumno3 = ["Mohamed", "Alí"]
alumno4 = ["Jean Claude", "Van Damme"]
alumno5 = ["Joe", "Frazier"]

#Variable que guarda los nombres de todos los alumnos
alumnosclase = [alumno1, alumno2, alumno3, alumno4, alumno5]

#Opción 2: Añade un nuevo alumno a la clase
def addAlumno ():
    """Esta funcion añade un nuevo alumno a la lista"""
    newalumno = [] #Creo la variable newalumno con el nombre y apellido del alumno
    print ("Introduce el nombre" + ":", end="")
    nombre =input()
    newalumno += [nombre] #Añado el nombre a la variable newalumno
    print ("Introduce el Apellido" + ":", end="")
    apellido = input()
    newalumno += [apellido] #Añado el apellido a la variable newalumno
    alumnosclase += [newalumno] #Añado el nombre completo del nuevo alumno a la lista de alumnos
    print (alumnosclase)
```

Llamo a la función

```
addAlumno ():
```

Me casca despues de elegir la opción y poner el apellido.

```
Introduce el nombre:juan
Introduce el Apellido:lopez
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Miguel\Documents\git\edu-python-estructurada-problema-alumnos-y-profesores\programa.py", line 87, in <module>
    addAlumno ()
  File "C:\Users\Miguel\Documents\git\edu-python-estructurada-problema-alumnos-y-profesores\programa.py", line 39, in addAlumno
    alumnosclase += [newalumno] #Añado el nombre completo del nuevo alumno a la lista de alumnos
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'alumnosclase' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muy interesante la pregunta. Primero lo que debes notar es que si en lugar de colocar:

```
alumnosclase += [newalumno]
```

... hicieras esto:

```
alumnosclase.append(newalumno)
```

...funcionaría, ¿por qué? Pues porque cuando llamas al operador `+` estás llamando al método `__add__` de Python. Este método crea un nuevo objeto en memoria, por lo que tu variable `alumnosclase` se sobreescribe antes de incluir al nuevo elemento. Es decir, vuelve a declarar la variable, así que como no está declarada con anterioridad la asignación `+=` falla.

Como recomendación, te diría que uses los métodos para listas `append()`, `extend()`... para trabajar con clases en lugar de los operadores matemáticos ya que [serán más eficientes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725782/in-python-what-is-the-difference-between-append-and/725882).

Más información [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766387/different-behaviour-for-list-iadd-and-list-add) y [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28119966/9167585).

Comment: Si, entiendo lo que quieres decir con lo alumnosclase.append(newalumno), , pero my profesor prefiere que de momento no usemos métodos para listas.
He resuelto el problema creando una copia de la variable nuevosalumnosclase = alumnosclase  dentro de la funcion addalumno()